# Not getting a segmentation fault when expecting it

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, undefined-behavior

I'm toying with buffer overflows, but I'm confused by what I'm finding when running the following simple C program on Mac OS.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

        char buf[2];

        scanf("%s", buf);

        printf("%s\n", buf);

}
```

By setting the length of buf to 2 bytes, I expected to cause a segmentation fault when entering the string "CCC", but that doesn't happen. Only when entering a string 24 characters in length do I incur a segmentation fault.

What's going on? Is it something to do with character encoding?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior of your program is undefined as soon as you overflow the buffer. Anything can happen. You can't predict it.

There might or might not be some padding bytes after your buffer that happen to be unimportant to your code execution. You can't rely on that. A different compiler, compiling in 32bit vs 64bit, debug settings... all that could alter your code execution after that overflow.

Comment: I see. I think the penny has dropped. A malicious attacker would be aiming to overflow the remainder of the stack and consequently overwrite a register? But, how would they predict the remainder of the stack? Will the OS allocate a fixed amount of memory every time?

Comment: Looking at the assembly output, and trial and error are your best bets to determine that "remainder of stack". It is possible, but not guaranteed at all, that that will remain the same for the executions of the _same binary_ in the _same environment_.  Buffer overflows don't overwrite registers. They overwrite the stack or heap.

Comment: @Martin the typical idea is to overflow the buffer that's on the stack in order to overwrite a bit of data on the stack that indicates where the CPU will go back to after returning from the function. For more details, try googling "smashing the stack".

Comment: Oh, so the attacker would fill up the stack with the 'shellcode'? But then, how does execution jump to the beginning of the shellcode? Sorry, I have a load of information in my head from various source and I'm trying to piece it all together. :)

Comment: I commented before I saw Karl's post. Thanks for the help, guys.

Answer (score 2):

Because `buf` is on the stack. When you start overwriting it, you start overwriting the stack which belongs to the program which the OS won't catch depending on what else is allocated there (e.g. spill slots for registers created by the compiler). Only once you cross the allocated stack boundary the OS will have a chance to raise a segfault.

Answer (score 1):

I **guess** it's related to the memory layout. If what you are overwriting is accessible to your process (a page mapped `writable`) the OS doesn't have a chance to see you're doing something "wrong".

Indeed, when doing something like this, from the eyes of a C programmer "that's totally wrong!". But in the eyes of the OS "Okay, he's writing stuff to some page. Is the page mapped with the adequate permissions ? If it is, OKAY".

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that you will get segmentation fault at all. There is more data after `char buf[2]` overwriting it may or may not cause segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

buf is allocated on the stack, you're just overwriting an area that's not used there is a good chance that nobody will complain about it. On some platforms your code will accept whole paragraphs.